# Function#apply shim

Tags: javascript, function, apply, shim

I'm building a collection of JavaScript native function patches, and I'm kind of stuck with shimming `Function.prototype.apply` method for old ies (<= v5). I use this piece of code to support `.apply` method, but I'm not completely sure if it is 'way to go' solution.. Some feedback would be welcome, thanks. Here's the code:

```
//
(function (pFunction, str, eval) {

    // (string) Function Class: '[object Function]'
    var funcstring = str.call(pFunction);

    var isfunc = function (node) {
        return funcstring === str.call(node);
    };

    // placeholder for private `.apply()` version
    var _apply;

    if (
        // have `.apply()`?
        !isfunc(pFunction.apply)
    ) {

        _apply = function (self, arr) {

            var func;

            //`this` should be a Function{}
            if (!isfunc(func = this)) 
              throw TypeError('Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible ' + func);

          // wrap primitives
          var wrapper = Object(arr);

          // throw for primitive argument, 
          // null/undefined are accepted by native `.apply()`
          if (!(
            (wrapper === arr) || (null == arr)
          )) throw TypeError('second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array');

          // build a string of `arr` argument
          // that can be passed to `.eval()`
          for (
            var 
              it = -1, len = wrapper.length, args = [];

            ++it < len; 

            args.push('arr['+ it +']')
          );

          var code = args.length ?
            'func.call(self,' + args.join(',') + ');':
            'func.call(self);';

          return eval(code);
        };

        pFunction.apply = function apply (self, arr) {
            return _apply.call(this, self, arr);
        };
    }

})(
  Function.prototype, 
  Object.prototype.toString, 
  eval
);

//eof
```

Comment: Old IE's <= v5? I doubt it makes any sense to shim these browsers.

Comment: First of all, this shim is useless, noone uses a browser that doesn't support `apply()` these days, and if you really need to support browsers that old you should be using `call()` to begin with, not `apply()`